# Printing to stdout gives the correct list, but appending to a list does not

Tags: python, permutation

I working on this problem on leetcode:

> Given a collection of distinct integers, return all possible permutations.

If I iteratively print my results I get the correct values.  As soon as I add it to a list the results are incorrect.  What is happening?

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return nums 

        permutations = list()
        import math
        max_swaps = math.factorial(len(nums))
        pair = [0,1]
        for i in range(max_swaps):
            if pair[1] == len(nums):
                pair[0] = 0
                pair[1] = 1
            p = self.swap(nums, pair[0], pair[1])
            print("Adding %s to the list" % p)
            permutations.append(p)
            pair[0] += 1
            pair[1] += 1
        return permutations

    def swap(self, nums, index1, index2):
        tmp = nums[index2]
        nums[index2] = nums[index1]
        nums[index1] = tmp
        return nums
```

I should get:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

But instead I get:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: You have a list full of references to *the same single list*, you don’t make copies anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep adding a reference to the same list to `permutations`.

When you call:

`permutations.append(p)`

Python doesn't take a copy of the list, it adds a reference. You only have one list.

What you want to do is:

`permutations.append(p[:])`

Which will take a copy.

Answer (score 2):

When you return `nums` from `swap`, you're not making a copy, you're returning the same list that will be modified later. You can make a copy either at the return or when you `append` the list to your result.

Comment: Personally, if the method was returning a copy I'd call it `swapped` instead of `swap`, following the "convention" of `sort` vs `sorted` and such.

Comment: @jbch You make a good point. I consider a function that modifies a list and also returns it to be a code smell. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796007/5987

Comment: that's fair, I didn't mention it but I would also make an in-place function return None, now that you mention it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common bug in a lot of code. The bug you're seeing here is a symptom of having the values returned from `swap` be the same as `nums`. This means that you're appending `nums` over and over into the permutations list. If you were to print the entire `permutations` list instead of only `p` you'd see that they were always the same.

The solution is rather simple: At some point in your code (likely in swap or something) you need to make a copy of the `nums` list.